# Use np.arange and the exponentiation operator ** to compute the first 30 powers of 2, starting from 2^0

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

In a jupyter notebook, the bottom code gives an asterick such that the kernel can't run and needs to restart. I find no other way to have it compute what its asking for in the problem. Is there another less computational way so as to not give an asterick (too much work for the kernel)?

> The powers of 2 (20=1, 21=2, 22=4, etc) arise frequently in computer
>   science. (For example, you may have noticed that storage on
>   smartphones or USBs come in powers of 2, like 16 GB, 32 GB, or 64 GB.)
>   Use np.arange and the exponentiation operator ** to compute the first
>   30 powers of 2, starting from 2^0.

```
    import numpy as np
    powers_of_2 = np.arange(2**0,2**30,2**1)
    powers_of_2
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compute the powers of two from power 0 to power 30. It computes EVERY number between `2**0` and `2**30` (in steps of 2).

Comment: Use `np.arange` to create the numbers from 1 to 30, and use the result of that as the exponent. Then numpy's element-wise application magic does the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compute 2 to the power of an array using the code below.

```
powers_of_2 = 2 ** np.arange(15)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use
2**np.arange(0,30,1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).